# Can a USB-only powered device be powered by an AC adaptor instead? Any voltage issues?

Tags: usb, power

I have a laptop cooling pad that is powered by USB. I would like to plug the cooler into a wall socket instead to free up a port. Can I use any USB/AC adapter to do this?

I know different adapters have different voltages, but does that make a difference here?

If it matters, this is the cooler: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B016CL2DE6/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016CL2DE6)
(The pad does have additional USB ports, but they're not reliable)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard for USB power from a Laptop is 5 Volts and normally 1/2 amp (some might be a bit more).

So yes you can use a standard USB Wall Wart that is rated at 5 Volts, 1 Amp. Should work just fine.

I have extra USB wall warts around for this purpose.

Comment: This answer is practically correct on this case - but its worth pointing out that USB devices can negotiate a higher voltage and/or work at a higher current if both sides specifically negotiate it. Also for the "simple/default" connection it doesn't t matter if the current rating on the power supply is greater then the fans need - devices will only pull as much power as they need.

Comment: I agree with your added point about the higher voltages, but this case was limited to the laptop (where 5 volts prevails) so I kept to that point.